# Pseudo element margin goes outside not inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm not sure whats wrong here but I can't get the margin of the pseudo element inside the element. Instead it goes outside of the parent. I've tried everything `clear, float, overflow, box-sizing etc.` but this time it won't work. Any recommendations?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var signaturePadCanvas = document.querySelector('#signature-pad-canvas');
  var parentWidth = jQuery(signaturePadCanvas).parent().outerWidth();
  signaturePadCanvas.setAttribute("width", parentWidth);
  var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(signaturePadCanvas);
});
```

```css
.signature-pad-canvas-wrapper {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.signature-pad-canvas-wrapper::after {
    content: 'Name';
    border-top: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    color: #cbcbcb;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 15px;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
<div class="signature-pad-canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="signature-pad-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: " I can't get the margin of the pseudo element inside the element. " what do you mean?

Comment: Do you see the border going outside of the parent? At the right side? This is wrong. It should have the same space as at the left between itself and the outer wrapper.

Comment: `left:0;right:0;` instead of `width:100%`

Comment: I believe you could use also `calc` to remove the space by the amount of added margin in the allotted area. `width: calc(100% - 30px)`;

Comment: @TemaniAfif That did it. Thanks a lot Temani! This kind of small things u know......